# Compile error in 'winbase.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I get the following error with a Windows file when compiling `winbase.h`.

Not sure why I get a syntax error and the compiler shows many more:

```
1> c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winbase.h(238) : 
   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Internal'
```

Here a simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <winbase.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you're missing a semi-colon.

Comment: Can you please post some of the code?  With just this error, it's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: You're probably missing a semi-colon right before you (in)directly included "winbase.h".

Comment: What files are being included by the file being compiled - and in what order?

Comment: Can you show us your code with the `#include`s?

Comment: In Visual Studio, the only include you ever really need is `<windows.h>`, so search above where that is.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Are you including `<winbase.h>` directly?

You shouldn't - it expects to have some things defined/declared before it's processed.  Specifically in this case the identifier `ULONG_PTR` which is declared as a typedef in `intsafe.h`.

Include `<windows.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing a `;` immediate before the `#include <windows.h>` line in your code.  Alternatively, there is some identifier-like text preceding the include file line.

```
int ABC
#include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is fine, and there is no missing semicolons before `#include "winbase.h"` then it should be a missing include before `winbase.h` (or one of the files that includes it).