# Compile errors of Eigen's unsupported/CXX11/Tensor module

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, eigen, eigen3

My project uses **Eigen-3.3-beta**. I can build my project in visual studio 2015 community which includes `<Eigen/Core>`. But after I include `<unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor>`, I got strange compile errors like these:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(46): error C3646: 'nLength': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(46): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C3646: 'lpSecurityDescriptor': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(48): error C3646: 'bInheritHandle': unknown override specifier
......
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(295): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

It seems that my project works properly with **Eigen-3.3-beta**'s normal part except `unsupported module`. What's more, with `unsupported module` included, types introduced by **GLEW** (e.g. `GLfloat`) cannot be resolved. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this stems from the include of  in `<unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor>`.

I solved it with help from this thread ([Compile error in 'winbase.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340722/compile-error-in-winbase-h) ) and just exchanged line 38 in `<unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor>` from `#include <winbase.h>` with `#include <windows.h>`.

Edit: This seems to be the way it was fixed in the lasted version in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the problem. We only added regression tests for windows recently, so we didn't catch this problem in time for the 3.3beta release. This has been fixed since and the fix will be part of the next release.